# Converting specific strings (numbers) from a list of lists to floats

Tags: python, list, floating-point

So I have a list of lists that contains strings:

```
[['10.00', 'name1'], ['8.50', 'name2'], ['7.50', 'name3'], ['15.00', 'name4'], ['12.50', 'name5'], ['9.50', 'name6']]
```

What I am trying to do is to convert only the numbers within all the lists to floats to get something like this:

```
[[10.00, 'name1'], [8.50, 'name2'], [7.50, 'name3'], [15.00, 'name4'], [12.50, 'name5'], [9.50, 'name6']]
```

Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: Start with baby steps: try to convert `'10.00'` to a *float*, then `['10.00', '13.67']`, then get to more complex cases like your current one.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are always going to be in that same spot you can do something like this for a quick solution

_list = [['10.00', 'name1'], ['8.50', 'name2'], ['7.50', 'name3'], ['15.00', 'name4'], ['12.50', 'name5'], ['9.50', 'name6']]

_list = [[float(n[0]), n[1]] for n in _list]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension if the first element is always a number.

```
lst = [['10.00', 'name1'], ['8.50', 'name2'], ['7.50', 'name3'], ['15.00', 'name4'], ['12.50', 'name5'], ['9.50', 'name6']]

lst = [[float(i[0]), i[1]] for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

the same as nepdavis posted, but with lambda expressions :3

```py
lst = [['10.00', 'name1'], ['8.50', 'name2'], ['7.50', 'name3'], ['15.00', 'name4'], ['12.50', 'name5'], ['9.50', 'name6']]

lst = map(lambda innerList: [float(innerList[0]), innerList[1]], lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on the first value being a number, you could just try to do the conversion, and if it fails return the original.

```
def to_float(n):
    try:
        return float(n)
    except ValueError:
        return n


lst = [['10.00', 'name1'], ['8.50', 'name2'], ['7.50', 'name3'], ['15.00', 'name4'], ['12.50', 'name5'], ['9.50', 'name6']]

lst = [[to_float(n) for n in N] for N in lst]

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, if the data is formatted right

```
import pandas as pd
lists = [['10.00', 'name1'], ['8.50', 'name2'], ['7.50', 'name3'], ['15.00', 'name4'], ['12.50', 'name5'], ['9.50', 'name6']]

listdf = pd.DataFrame(lists)

listdf[0] = listdf[0].astype(float)
```